# How can I split string elements of an array and add them to another?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, substring

Using an array list of names, I am trying to split the first names and surnames using a for loop. The code works but when splitting the names using a substring it goes from 0-x (x being the space between the names) but it reads from 0 each time and adds each name multiple times until it completes. How can I run it from the next element each time to skip the name previously split and added?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [] name_list = {"lee momo", "michael jesus", "kim danger", "dean habbo"};

    ArrayList<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> surnames = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < name_list.length; i++){
        int x = name_list[i].indexOf(" ");
        String firstName = name_list[i].substring(0, x);
        firstNames.add(firstName);

        for(int j = 0; j < name_list.length; j++){
            int y = name_list[i].indexOf(" ");
            String surname = name_list[i].substring(x);
            surnames.add(surname);
        }
        
        System.out.println(firstNames.toString());
        System.out.println(surnames.toString());

    }
}
```

For example the output of first names is like this:
lee
lee, michael
lee, michael, kim
lee, michael, kim, dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fix

You need only one loop, to extract both

```
String[] name_list = {"lee momo", "michael jesus", "kim danger", "dean habbo"};
ArrayList<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> surnames = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < name_list.length; i++) {
    int x = name_list[i].indexOf(" ");
    String firstName = name_list[i].substring(0, x);
    firstNames.add(firstName);
    String surname = name_list[i].substring(x + 1);
    surnames.add(surname);
}
System.out.println(firstNames); // [lee, michael, kim, dean]
System.out.println(surnames); // [momo, jesus, danger, habbo]
```

#### Improve

- use `String.split()`
- use a for each loop

```
for (String s : name_list) {
    String[] parts = s.split("\\s+");
    firstNames.add(parts[0]);
    surnames.add(parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: So the duplicate names being added was because of the second for loop, not because of the substring being set to 0-x?

Comment: @Rednuam yes, the second add the surname again and again

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < name_list.length; i++){
    String[] split_name = name_list[i].split(" ");
    int x = name_list[i].indexOf(" ");

    String firstName = name_list[i].substring(0,x);
    firstNames.add(firstName);
    //indexOf would be useful when surname has space separated more tahn
    // one owrd
    String surname = name_list[i].substring(x+1);
    surnames.add(surname);

}

for(int i=0; i<firstNames.size(); ++i){
    
    System.out.println(firstNames.get(i));
    System.out.println(surnames.get(i));
}
```